# Dynamically creating HTML and asp elements from code behind

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I am filling a DataTable in the code behind my webpage and trying to use it to create a "p" tag which has text of the service option followed by an ASPxCheckBox. Problem that I'm having is that I can't seem to get them within the same line, they are separated. Any assistance would be greatly.

The code so far:

```
        Dim dtExample As New DataTable
        dtExample.Columns.Add("ID")
        dtExample.Columns.Add("Option")
        dtExample.Columns.Add("Price", GetType(Decimal))
        dtExample.Rows.Add({1, "Engine Flush", 99.95})
        dtExample.Rows.Add({2, "Oil Check", 19.95})
        dtExample.Rows.Add({3, "Pump Up Tires", 9.95})
        dtExample.Rows.Add({4, "Air Conditioner", 69})
        dtExample.Rows.Add({5, "Brake Fluid Checker", 49.95})


        For Each row As DataRow In dtExample.Rows
            Dim cb As New DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxCheckBox
            Dim ParaElement As New HtmlGenericControl

            ParaElement.InnerHtml = "<p class='serviceoption center' id='" & row("ID") & "'>" & row("Option") & "</p>"
            cb.ID = row("ID")
            cb.Checked = False
            cb.Visible = True
            cb.ClientInstanceName = row("ID")
            serviceoptions.Controls.Add(ParaElement)
            serviceoptions.Controls.Add(cb)
        Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devexpress controls can be difficult to style in some cases. Rather than wrapping your checkboxes within a `p` tag, I would suggest setting the `CssClass` property of the `AspxCheckbox`to a CSS class containing your styling, and setting the descriptive text of the checkbox by using the `Text` property rather than a `p` tag.

Answer (score 0):

a P is a paragraph, if memory serves me right that will always be on a new line.

I suspect you want something like this but using css instead of the inline styles shown below

```
<div style="float:left;margin-right:10px;">Your Text</div>
<div style="float:left;clear:right;">Your Checkbox</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but floating the elements just caused more issues, e.g needing "br"s to separate elements then the background was floated and wouldn't fill the area.